# jQuery UI Dialog will not open

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to bring up a jQuery UI Dialog in response to form input. Consider:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
      <script src="checkLogin.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form>
         <label>User Name:</label><input onkeydown="checkSubmitKey(event)"><br>
         <input id="submit" name="submit" type="button" onclick="checkLogin()" value="Submit">
      </form>
      <div id="dialog" title="Alert" style="display: none;"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

where `checkLogin.js` is:

```
function checkSubmitKey(ev) {
    if(ev.keyCode == 13) {
        checkLogin();
    }
}

function checkLogin() {
   showAlert("Hello");
}

function showAlert(str) {
    $( "#dialog" ).html(str);
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
        modal: true,
        title: "Alert",
        buttons: {
            "OK": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is that the Dialog only shows when I press the "Submit" button; if I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the "User Name" text field, nothing happens.

(If I change function `checkLogin` to

```
function checkLogin() {
   alert("ok");
   showAlert("Hello");
}
```

the Dialog appears when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> also.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prevent the default action of the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. Change the JS to:

```
function checkSubmitKey(ev) {
    if(ev.keyCode == 13) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        checkLogin();
    }
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/MaUyL/4/)

Comment: Just curious: What is exactly the default behavior that must be prevented? And why does this behavior inhibit the dialog from appearing?